# Better way to parallelize my nth factorial python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have this python code to calculate the nth factorial of n "1"s in a row. I've been able to optimize it very well, including adjusting it to run on all cores using the multiprocessing module. However I have noticed the 7th process (Which is the lower end of the values since I'm going from the top down) is significantly faster than the rest of the threads. Threads 0-6 take on average 32 seconds with n=11 where-as thread 7 only takes 12 seconds. I would've expecting a difference the larger the numbers themselves got, but I wouldn't expect an immediate wall with such a stark difference.

Is there something in my code that I have missed other than the calculation that causes this huge wall? I've verified the output and each segment is nearly identical length (thread 7 is slightly longer by a few dozen calculations, but in the grand scheme of things this is nothing and thread 7 is the shortest running anyways)

Is there a better way to parallelize this for better efficiency? Would making the threads not all the same increment be helpful?

Edit: Adding python version information

Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

(I did 25 tests of n=11, all very similar to this run)

[image: Duration of each Process]

```
import multiprocessing
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
from math import log10

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.HelpFormatter,
    description="Calcs n factorial",
    usage=""
)

parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int, default=2)

args = parser.parse_args()

def getlog(send_end, i, threads, num, n, inc):
    begin = datetime.now()
    start = num-inc*i
    end = num-inc*(i+1) if i < threads-1 else 0
    output = sum(map(log10, range(start, end, -n)))
    send_end.send(output)
    final = datetime.now()
    duration = final-begin
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(i, duration, start, end))

def main():
    n = args.number
    num = int('1'*n)
    threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() if num/multiprocessing.cpu_count() > multiprocessing.cpu_count() else 1
    inc = int(num/threads)
    inc -= inc%n
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for i in range(threads):
        recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getlog, args=(send_end, i, threads, num, n, inc))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    e = sum([output.recv() for output in pipe_list])

    print('%.2fe%d' % (10**(e % 1), e // 1))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.now()
    main()
    end = datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` uses a slower implementation if it needs to work with values beyond the range of a C `long` - see the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/rangeobject.c#L707).

You're on Windows, where C `long` is 32-bit (even on a 64-bit Python build). Process 7 is the only one where the range elements fit within the bounds of a C `long`.

Comment: (This is basically superb rain's hypothesis, but with a source link and adjusted for the comment that you're running a 64-bit build on Windows.)

Comment: Interesting. So even if you're running 64-bit python on 64-bit windows C long is still the 32-bit integer limit. Do you have of any methods for improving performance past this?

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, I ran 32-bit Python on my Windows and 64-bit Python on repl.it's Linux, not realizing the OS would make the difference rather than the Python bit-version. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm... then I guess my suggestion to make all threads/ranges go through all magnitudes would actually be counter-productive. It won't make the slow ones faster, it'll only make the fast one as slow as the others. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

Times for iterating a million numbers at different magnitudes:

```
from timeit import repeat
from collections import deque

for e in range(26, 36):
    n = 2**e
    t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(range(n, n+10**6), 0), number=1))
    print(e, t)
```

Output for me on 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows, note the huge increase when going from 2<sup>30</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>:

```
26 0.020830399999999916
27 0.020713199999999987
28 0.02067260000000004
29 0.021565000000000056
30 0.021966000000000152
31 0.16404839999999998
32 0.16630840000000013
33 0.16394810000000026
34 0.16302989999999973
35 0.1655395999999998
```

Mapping `log10` over the ranges still shows about the same (absolute) increase:

```
26 0.14502039999999994
27 0.1435571
28 0.14378349999999962
29 0.14398270000000002
30 0.14687919999999988
31 0.29700239999999933
32 0.29499730000000035
33 0.2949491999999996
34 0.2964432000000006
35 0.2918921999999995
```

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from collections import deque
from math import log10

for e in range(26, 36):
    n = 2**e
    t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(map(log10, range(n, n+10**6)), 0), number=1))
    print(e, t)
```

<strike>And your numbers in thread 7 are all of fast magnitudes while most/all numbers in the other threads are of slow magnitudes.</strike>

You could change your ranges so that they all go through all magnitudes. Simpler example: Instead of ranges `range(0, 10)` and `range(10, 20)`, use ranges `range(0, 20, 2)` and `range(1, 20, 2)`.

Btw, I see a similar increase for 64-bit Python on 64-bit Windows when going from 2<sup>30</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>. But on 64-bit Python on Linux I see no increase when going from 2<sup>30</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>, but a similarly dramatic increase when going from 2<sup>62</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>.

**Update:**

The above striked-through paragraphs aren't right. As [user2357112 supports Monica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63370617/13008439) shows, it's not that "the numbers" are slow (which I had thought) but that there are two entirely separate `range` implementations. And only your thread 7 uses the fast one (the one for small numbers). So my above suggestion to make all threads/ranges go through all magnitudes would actually be counter-productive. It won't make the slow ones faster, it'll only make the fast one as slow as the others. Bummer.

So alternative suggestion: Instead of giving each thread one range like you do, give each thread a part of the `long`-range and a part of the non-`long` range. That should make all threads equally fast, and reduce the overall time a bit. But the effect will be small, even smaller for larger n, and I doubt it's worth the complication.

Comment: No, I'm running it on 64bit. 64 bit installed. Sys_maxsize = 2^64-1. Python 3.8.5 [MSc v.1924 64bit (amd64)] on win32.

Comment: Hmm, ok... but can you run my two tests and tell the results?

Comment: 26 0.03331709999999999,
27 0.03348040000000002,
28 0.03309680000000004,
29 0.033139699999999994,
30 0.07700340000000006,
31 0.1269125000000002,
32 0.12607709999999983,
33 0.12669620000000004,
34 0.12609989999999982,
35 0.12720019999999987.
This with the last code block of range, which would make sense with the other comment by user2357112 supports Monica.

Comment: I've also put together going through all the ranges of numbers. Going from num-(n*i) to 0 with a step of thread_count*n. Where num is the start of the number (111,1111,etc.), i is the current thread(0->thread_count) and thread_count is the threads available. This produces the same result, and allows all the processes to take nearly identical times. However it increases the total processing time by ~8%. I can send a paste of the new implementation if you'd like.

Comment: @Kadragon Yeah, that's what I expected after reading that other answer. Sad. Have a look at the "Update" section I added to my answer.

Comment: Agreed, it likely isn't worth the complication. At N=11, the range below 2**32 is ~19% of the total set. Optimizing this would allow the total runtime of each tread to probably be 26-28 seconds at best. This optimization also decreases by almost exactly 1 OOM each increase in N, making it useless at N=12+. And it's not worth for N=11 and below since they're already fast enough it's not worth the time increase. Do you know of any possible methods of speeding up the processing of these large numbers?

Comment: @Kadragon Maybe there's a version of [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for nth factorials and it's accurate enough for you?

Comment: Sadly I don't see anything for nth factorial. Only for the first logarithm m. But I can look around a little harder. I originally thought numpy would be beneficial, but sadly it appears numpy struggles with really large numbers, or I implemented it completely wrong.

Comment: @Kadragon Maybe write a question about your NumPy attempt then :-). I do think it should be faster.

Comment: @Kadragon I have a suspicion about numpy's struggle and what to do about it. And if I'm not mistaken, these are called multifactorials and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalized_Stirling_numbers_expanding_the_multifactorial_functions) might be useful (but at first sight it looks intimidating and I don't have the desire to look into it).